# can't update with this error messg

Tags: shell, command-line, networking, ssh, kernel

I got this message:

> not enough free disk space.... The upgrade needs a total of 31.8 M
>   free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 31.8 M
>   of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary
>   packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'

I'm really not that good of a user and have very little experience with Linux. I'd like some help with how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using Ubuntu. Ubuntu often keeps back the older kernel packages after an upgrade.
All these kernels are stored in your /boot directory which is often kept very small.

You can check the free space you have left, by running:

```
$ df -h
```

In order to upgrade, you need to remove a few of your older kernels. To do this, first identify the kernel you are currently running:

```
$ uname -r
```

This will give you an output like:

```
3.8.6-1-ARCH
```

Next, list all the kernels that reside in your `/boot` directory:

```
$ ls /boot | grep vmlinuz
```

Now, you must uninstall all but the most recent (The one with the largest number) kernels. To do this, first list all the packages that were installed for that kernel:

```
dpkg -l | grep ^ii | grep 2.6.28-15 | awk -F' ' '{ print $2 }'
```

Where 2.6.28-15 is the version of the kernel I am uninstalling. This gives a list like:

```
linux-headers-2.6.28-15
linux-headers-2.6.28-15-generic
linux-image-2.6.28-15-generic
linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-15-generic
```

Now to remove these:

```
$ sudo aptitude remove linux-headers-2.6.28-15 linux-headers-2.6.28-15-generic linux-image-2.6.28-15-generic linux-restricted-modules-2.6.28-15-generic
```

Or, you could use the following one-liner:

```
# dpkg -l linux-* | awk '/^ii/{ print $2}' | grep -v -e `uname -r | cut -f1,2 -d"-"` | grep -e [0-9] | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

**WARNING**: Always be wary of commands you find online. The above one-liner is not my own and I take no responsibility for it. Follow the steps given above and you should be safe enough.

Comment: The one-liner at the end looks reasonably safe to me. It can be made another bit safer by replacing the `-y` parameter to apt-get with `--simulate` to get an output detailing what would be done. Once satisfied that it is safe, `--simulate` can be removed for an actual run.

Comment: It looks safe to me too. I would not post anything without understanding it first. However, I am always a little wary about automating such things.

Comment: We are in agreement about that.

Answer (score 1):

I think for starters you can run the command that the error message is suggesting you run in a terminal. Assuming you're running Ubuntu.

1. open terminal window: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
2. type the command: `sudo apt-get clean`
3. provide your password when prompted